# Classification of second order linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have been looking at the classification of the second order linear PDEs and came across two different definition

If a PDE is defined as following:

$$Au_{xx}+Bu_{xy}+Cu_{yy}+Du_x+Eu_y+Fu = G$$

Then the discriminant is:

$$\Delta = B^2 -4AC.......(i)$$

But if the PDE is defined as following:

$$au_{xx}+2bu_{xy}+cu_{yy}+du_x+eu_y+fu = g$$
so is the discriminant:

$$\Delta = b^2 -4ac.......(ii)$$

If we take an example for instance : $u_{xx}+4u_{xy}+4u_{yy}= 0$

According to equation (i), A=1, B=4 and C=4

$$\rightarrow \Delta=0$$

so it is Parabolic

but according to equation (ii), a=1, b=2 and c=4
$$\rightarrow \Delta=-12<0$$
so it Elliptic.

So what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: The discriminant $(ii)$ should be $b^2-ac$, just like the expression for the second order equations.